An exercise in ''The axiom of choice'' 8.12 (page 131)
Theorem 8.12 of Jech's Axiom of Choice (page 131) states that for any regular cardinal $\kappa$, there is a permutation model where Dependent Choice fails and $\mathsf{AC_\lambda}$
holds for every $\lambda < \kappa$. In the construction of the permutation model, the set $A$ of future atoms is ${}^{<\omega}\kappa$, i.e. the set of all finite sequences of ordinals less than $\kappa$, and the ideal $I$ is defined as follows: for any $E\subseteq A$, $E\in I$ iff $|E|<\kappa$ and $E$ is downward-closed
(i.e. closed under initial segments) and well-founded, as a subtree of $(A, \subseteq)$.
Towards showing that $\mathsf{AC_\lambda}$ holds, we fix a collection $X=\{X_\gamma \mid \gamma<\lambda\}$ of nonempy sets. For each $\gamma<\lambda$, we choose some $y_{\lambda}\in X_{\lambda}$ and some $E_{\lambda}\in I$ such that $E\subseteq E_{\lambda}$ and $E_{\lambda}$ is a support of $y_{\lambda}$.
My question is how to use recursion on $\gamma$ to find an automorphisms $\pi_{\gamma}$ such that $\pi_{\gamma}\in\text{fix}(E)$ for each $\gamma$ and $\pi_{\gamma}(E_{\gamma})\cap\pi_{\kappa}(E_{\kappa})=E$ whenever $\gamma\neq\kappa$. It seems that I need to permute all the point out of E. But I don't know how to do this, especially in the case of limit ordinals.

Suppose you have defined $\pi_\gamma$ for all $\gamma < \delta$ for some $\delta < \lambda$. Try to define $\pi_\delta$ by recursion on the (finite) length of the elements of $A$.

Thank you for your helpful hint!
